# Proof of Brouwer fixed point theorem using Stokes's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

$\omega$ is the volume form on the boundary

B -ball

$f\colon B \to \partial B$

$$
0 < \int_{\partial B}\omega = \int_{\partial B} f^*(\omega) = \int_{B} df^*(\omega) = \int_B f^*(d\omega) = \int_B(0) = 0
$$

What I do not understand, is why on the left, we may conclude that

1. $\int_{B}  d \omega = \int_{\partial B}  \omega > 0  $

where as later we are alowed to conclude

2. $\int_{B}  f^*(d\omega$) =0

as $d\omega=0$

What puzzles me is, what prevents us from concluding that $d\omega=0$ in 1.

Both 1. and 2. are integrated over B, so where does the difference come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the equation
$$
    \int_{\partial \Omega} \alpha = \int_{\Omega} d\alpha
$$
it is assumed that $\alpha$ is defined on $\Omega$.  If $i\colon\partial\Omega\to\Omega$ is the inclusion, it induces a restriction map $i^*$ on differential forms in the opposite direction. Really the $\alpha$ on the left-hand side is $i^*\alpha$. We don't usually bother with this extra notation, but it matters.

In general $i^*$ is not an injection.  Let's consider the $n=2$ case.  So $B$ is the unit disk and $\partial B$ is the unit circle.  Let $\alpha = x\,dy - y\,dx$ and $\omega = i^*\alpha$.  In other words, $\alpha$ is an extension of $\omega$ from $\partial B$ to $B$.  We have
$$
    d\alpha = 2\, dx\wedge dy
$$
which is definitely not zero on the unit disk.
But $i^*(d\alpha)=di^*\alpha = d\omega$ *is* zero, by dimension count (it's a two-form on a one-manifold).

To say the same thing without the $i^*$, it is possible for $\omega$ to extend from $\partial B$ to $B$, and for $d\omega =0$ to be true on $\partial B$, but $d\omega \neq 0$ on $B$.  This is what's happening here.

Now back to your proof.  Suppose $\omega$ is a volume form on $\partial B$ (we are no longer assuming that $\omega = i^*\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ on $B$; maybe it is, maybe it isn't).  If $f \colon B \to \partial B$ were a retraction, then $f \mathbin{\circ} i = \operatorname{id}_{\partial B}$.  Then on differential forms, $i^* \mathbin{\circ} f^* = \operatorname{id}_{\Omega^*(\partial B)}$.  Therefore
$$\begin{split}
\int_{\partial B}\omega &= \int_{\partial B}i^*(f^*\omega) \\
&= \int_B d(f^*\omega) \qquad\text{(by Stokes)} \\
&= \int_B f^*(d\omega) \\
&= \int_B f^*(0) \qquad\text{(by dimension count)} \\
&= 0
\end{split}$$
If $\omega$ is a volume form on $\partial B$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I may ask, for clarification. If  $i^*\alpha$ is always assumed, why isn't $di^*\alpha$ always = 0? It makes sense to me, that it isn't, as it would mean all integrals would be zero. Perhaps I don't understand the inclusion. Might you offer a follow-up? I would be really grateful. In other words, where does this i* come from, and why is it usually ommited?

Comment: If I may reformulate:     $\int_{\partial \Omega} \alpha = \int_{\Omega} d\alpha$ assumes    $ \int_{\partial \Omega} i^*\alpha = \int_{\Omega} d\alpha$ and not    $ \int_{\partial \Omega} i^*\alpha = \int_{\Omega} d(i^*\alpha)$ ? I'm afraid to say, I have never seen this i*. Might you offer a few words on it? Why is it there? In any case, a well written answer, thank you.

Comment: Is it there, because in order for the theorem to hold, $\alpha$ must be defined on ${\Omega}$ even though we integrate it (on the left side) over ${\partial\Omega}$? Or is it there in general? My concern is if $$
    \int_{\partial \Omega} i^*\alpha = \int_{\Omega} di^*\alpha  = \int_{\Omega} i^*d\alpha
$$ and $d\alpha=0$. Which is obviously not true. Sorry for the confusion on my side...

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer: $i^*$ is there to ensure that whatever form we are integrating is defined on on the manifold over which we are integrating it.  If $\alpha$ is defined on $\Omega$, $i^*\alpha$ is defined on $\partial\Omega$, so we can integrate $i^*\alpha$ over $\partial\Omega$.  But you can't integrate $i^*\alpha$ (or $i^*$ of anything) over $\Omega$; the range of $i^*$ consists of forms on $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I'm slowly getting it. Slowly...
$$ \omega = i^*\alpha$$
$$\int_{\partial B}\omega = \int_{\partial B}i^*\alpha$$ above:defined on $\partial B$  
$$\int_{\partial B}i^*(f^*\alpha) = $$
$$=\int_{\ B}d(f^*\alpha)=\int_{\ B}f^*d(\alpha) $$ above: Why is this $d\alpha$ =0, if there is no $ i^*$, and we're integrating over B? Why isn't it considered a 2-form on a 2 manifold here? I'm lost...

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer: In paragraph 1, $\alpha$ is a variable; just any form on $\Omega$ of degree $\dim(\Omega)-1$.  In paragraph 2, I chose a specific $\alpha$ (and $\omega$).  In paragraph 4, let $\alpha = f^*\omega$ and apply Stokes's theorem as it appears in paragraph 1.

Comment: I think I understand now
$$\int_B f^*(d\omega) $$
$$\int_B f^*(0) $$
The second step can be made, only because f is a refraction, thus al integration is done on a n-1 manifold. I kept thinking that wasn't the case, because $f^*(0)$ has yet to be applied and that bothered me, how can it be generally zero and not zero.

Comment: Difference between these two got me
$$\int_B f^*(d\omega)  = \int_B(0)$$
and
$$\int_B f^*(d\omega)  = \int_B f^*(0)$$
The second seemed to me as if $(d\omega)$=0 regardles of what f is, and that confused me. Again, thank you for your many replies. I hope I finally understand.